# Simple upload speed test

Tags: java, file-upload, upload, httpurlconnection, speed-test

I created simple upload speed test, see code below:

```
try {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    byte [] array = new byte [1 * 1024 * 1024]; // 1 Mb data test
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    multipartEntity.addPart("", new ByteArrayBody(array, MIME.ENC_BINARY, ""));
    conn.addRequestProperty(multipartEntity.getContentType().getName(), multipartEntity.getContentType().getValue());

    conn.setReadTimeout(connTimeout);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(connTimeout);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    dataStream.write(array);

    String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.
    String boundary = multipartEntity.getContentType().getValue().replaceAll(".*boundary=", "");
    dataStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + CRLF);

    dataStream.flush();
    dataStream.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();    
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        long speed = Math.round(array.length/ (end-start));
        } else {
            // something went wrong
        }
```

Everything works perfect, but I have small problem. On fast networks like wifi it takes less than second to send 1 Mb of data. But on slower networks it takes maybe 10-30 seconds, depending on network and signal. So I realize, that it would be much better to not upload data with fixed length, but use something like time limit - so uploading data not more than for example 3 seconds.

Question is simple :) How to implement this - I mean sending data, computing time in same moment, and when the limit expires just stop sending, see how much I sent and compute speed?

Answer (score 2):

How about using something like a binary search, so you start with a small amount of data and keep doubling in size until your resulting time is long enough for a reasonable idea of the bandwidth.

Comment: hm, I thought it would be best do something like this:
while (notExpiredTimeLimit) {
send to server (another 1000 bytes of my array)
}
Problem is, that I really do not know how to do this....As it looks that data are sending to server in line conn.getResponseCode() what makes impossible for me to do anything with it :)

Answer (score 1):

the amount of bytes you send is not *that* important. even if you upload 50 KB when you divide that by the milliseconds the upload took (for fast connections that number will be relatively small) the division will result in a relatively big number. Conclusion: be safe and reduce the amount of bytes you send.